# How do you change the node port?

Tags: nodeos

I am setting up eosio on my mac and when I try to run tail -f nodeos.log I get this error  ::plugin_startup failed to bind to port  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ports used by nodeos, p2p connection (9876) and http connection (8888).
You can change them by adding options when you execute nodeos like:

```
nodeos --p2p-listen-endpoint=0.0.0.0:9876 --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888
                                     ^^^^                               ^^^^
                                     change number here                 here too
```

You can put those options into config.ini of nodeos. If you want to allow http connection within localhost only, set `http-server-address` to `127.0.0.1:PORT` instead of `0.0.0.0:PORT`.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to put those options into config.ini and I am still getting the same error message. I think I don't have it in the right place.

Comment: Also what do i change the numbers too because i tried to run what you provided me and i still see the same error

Comment: Oh, you need to use different numbers in example, not 9876 and 8888. Change them to any other numbers.

Comment: ok so i did that but then it says connection refused

Comment: What connection? If you mean cleos, you need to set url explicitly, because cleos tries to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8888 by default. Try `cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:YOUR_CHANGED_PORT get info`.

Comment: It says connection failed to p2p.eos.io:9876: Connection refused
I even tried running hard replay and I still get that error.

Comment: Where does `p2p.eos.io` come from? I haven't heard that block.one provides that kind of url.

Comment: it was already in my config.ini file

Comment: That is an example (not real), so you don't need to use option like `p2p-peer-address = p2p.eos.io:9876`. You can ignore that error message. `p2p-peer-address` means the url of other nodes you want to connect. If you just try to make local testnet, you don't need any `p2p-peer-address`. BTW, did you modify `config.ini` by yourself, or download it from somewhere?

Comment: I modified by myself